# how spring MVC handles multipage form?

Tags: spring-mvc

**how to handle multi page form in spring MVC.**

can anyone help me achieve multi page form in spring mvc?

Comment: first result searching spring multi page forms: http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-handling-multipage-forms-with-abstractwizardformcontroller/

Comment: thanks but AbstractWizardFormController is depricated in new version of spring

Comment: maybe spring webflow can help you http://projects.spring.io/spring-webflow/

Comment: can not be do this in spring mvc

Comment: Like @mserioli said you can use Spring WebFlow. It's the tool for the job in your case. You could also do it with a session, but that would be quite cumbersome.

Comment: can you please suggest some example with session